# How to install jquery in vue project

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

I created a laravel 6 project and set frontend preset vue and created some vue components with using bootstrap.Ex:Navbar and Modal when i tried to open modal with `$('#modalName').modal('show');` nothing happened

So i think this is a jquery problem.I installed already bootstrap and jquery with (npm install)

This is my bootstrapjs

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
}
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

And appjs

````
window.Vue = require('vue');
import App from './components/App';
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template:'<App/>',
    components: {App}
});```

error message not found the modal function

`$(..).modal('show');`
````

Comment: By Default, I believe `Vue` ships with `JQuery` although I don't know the version you are using.

Comment: your error message states that `modal` function is not found, jquery is already available to you.

Comment: Did you include app.js in the main blade file ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.js`, you did not include `bootstrap.js` that's why it is not working.

Include boostrap.js in app.js at the top as shown below

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

if we dont import it then `axios` will also not work because it is imported in bootstrap.js which is not included in `app.js`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, Laravel 6 has a new UI pack .First of all ,We need to install this packet and all files working correctly.